# how I can return more than one value from windows to unix-AIX?

Tags: windows-server-2003, unix, command-line-interface, aix, return-path

i'm have to server:-
1-windows-server 2003
2-UNIX-AIX

I execute something in windows server and now I want to return some value from windows to unix .... how I can do it

I install copssh in windows server and openssh in unix server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more details about exactly what needs to be executed would be helpful - is it a one-off, or something that will be scheduled?  Can you initiate it from the AIX server or must it be controlled from the Windows server?

You could start the windows executable remotely, over an SSH connection from the AIX server.  Any value or output will be returned over the tunnel.

Alternatively, a script on the windows server could initiate an SSH tunnel back to the AIX server; either to write the returned value to a file or run a process and pass the data to it.

Comment: Click on Osama's name to view his profile. You will see he has several questions, many related to this one.